# Temperamental JavaScript: function works only sometimes

Tags: javascript, function, variables, getelementsbyclassname, typeerror

I have a javascript function that is only working sometimes. I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined` sometimes and sometimes the function works as expected.

To clearly explain and demonstrate the issue I recorded this short video: https://youtu.be/uSSes2_DPXU

Here is my function:

```
function openLightBox() {
    var itemId = event.target.id; 
    var lightBox = document.getElementsByClassName(itemId);
    console.log(lightBox);
    lightBox[0].style.display = 'block' ;
}
```

**SOLUTION**

Final HTML:

```
<a onClick="openLightBox(<?php echo get_the_ID()?>)">
```

Final JS:

```
function openLightBox(id) {
    var lightBox = document.getElementsByClassName(id);

    console.log(lightBox);
    lightBox[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: You are taking id from target but search by className. Maybe you meant to use getElementById() js method?

Comment: can you provide simple jsfiddle? add sample html also.

Comment: @Silwerclaw id element can be same as css class :-)

Comment: what show `console.log`?

Comment: try add `event` as parameter in function: `function openLightBox(event) {`

Comment: @Grundy https://jsfiddle.net/dLvom271/ 

I tried adding event as a param in the function but it didn't help.

Comment: @LukeBailey, as say Tim, your problem with `target`. In snippet in my answr you can look how it can change depends on where clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it sometimes works, and I'm a bit guessing here, depends on where on the element you click. Since you have wrapped your `a` tag around the `div` that holds the id, does your `a` tag nicely wrap around the `div` dimension wise?

Actually it would make more sense to add the id to the `a` tag.

```
<a onClick="openLightBox(<?php echo get_the_ID()?>)">
```

Then your function will be someting like this:

```
function openLightBox(id) {
    var lightBox = document.getElementById(id);

    console.log(lightBox);
    lightBox.style.display = 'block';
}
```

[extra info: event bubbling and target -vs- currentTarget](http://www.qc4blog.com/?p=650)

Answer (score 1):

You use `event.target` a bit wrong. So in snippet below you can see that target change depends where you click.

```js
function openlightbox(e) {
  console.log(e);
  document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = e.target.outerHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.title {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
h3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a onclick="openlightbox(event)">
    <div class='overlay' id="v1">
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>category</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</article>
<pre id='target'></pre>
```

For solving you can just pass it directly to function. Or add event handler with `addEventHandler` function

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('article a.open');
console.log(a);
for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
  console.log(a[i],a[i].addEventListener);
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = e.target.outerHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML += '<br /> this.id:'+ this.id;
    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML += '<br /> this:'+ this.outerHTML.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
  },false);
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.title {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
h3 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <a class="open" href="#"  id="v1">
    <div class='overlay'>
      <div class="title">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>category</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</article>
<pre id='target'></pre>
```